# Code Indentations in Cmder

Tags: linux, ssh, python, cmder

I commonly use Cmder to ssh into Linux boxes where I run Python scripts regularly.  Unfortunately, when I copy and paste indented code, the paste action seems to interpret my spaces incorrectly.  for example, the lines:

```
def test(x):
    print(x)
    x+=1
    print(x)
```

paste as:

```
def test(x):
        print(x)
            x+=1
                print(x)
```

I'd like to have the pasted text spaced the same as the original.  This works fine in Putty.

Comment: Which ssh do you try? Which python do you run? Have you tried official ConEmu?

Comment: I didn't include the SSH version as it seems to be a problem with Cmder, as it works fine in Putty from windows or any ssh client form a Linux box. The problem seems to only happen in Cmder. Python versioning is inconsequential for the purposes for this question, as I am coping and pasting into a text editor (happening in any text editor I use). I have not tried ConEmu proper, was hoping to stay with Cmder as it solves alot of my other requirements.